# reactjs: why some dom elements defined in `render` show twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, I got some code to work with bootstrap-daterangepicker, but some how there's one dom component in my React class `render` shows twice.

I defined the class like this:

```
var DateRangePicker = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="daterangepicker-container">
                <div className="daterangepicker-label"> Created between:</div>
                <div id={this.props.datepicker_id} className="daterangepicker-content">
                    <i className="icon-calendar icon-large"></i>
                    <span></span> <b className="caret"></b>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The `<span></span>` is the place holder of the date range text. I did in the `daterangepicker` plugin:

`$(this).find("span").html(display_date(start, end));`

However, after the page is loaded, I see two `<span></span>` next to each other with exact same text. I inspected the Elements:

```
<div id="new_daterange" class="daterangepicker-content" data-reactid=".4.1.1">
    <i class="icon-calendar icon-large" data-reactid=".4.1.1.0"></i>
    <span data-reactid=".4.1.1.1">October 26th, 2015 - November 9th, 2015</span>
    <span data-reactid=".4.1.1.2">October 26th, 2015 - November 9th, 2015</span>
    <b class="caret" data-reactid=".4.1.1.3"></b>
</div>
```

I installed the react chrome debugger and check the console:

```
<div id="new_daterange" className="datepicker-content">
    <i className="icon-calendar icon-large'></i>
    <span/>
    " "
    <b className="caret"/>
</div>
```

If I do "show in Element pane" for the quotes under `<span/>`, it corresponds to the second `<span></span>` in html. This beats me pretty bad and I couldn't figure out what's going on.

Comment: does react really leave all those janky `data-reactid` attribs behind?

Comment: @dandavis I don't really have enough knowledge to understand how are those `data-reactid` generated, but they indeed show up when I inspect the source. I'm wondering if there's a way to debug/dig into the process to find it out.

Comment: perhaps `$(this).find("span").slice(0,1).html(...` would solve your problem...

Comment: @dandavis: Yea I can do that like `$(this).first("span")`, which might be my final solution if I couldn't find any help. But well, the problem is still there :)

Comment: I'd advise you to use something more specific than just `span` as your placeholder. Give it an ID. It's possible that React is rendering its own spans into the dom and your `$(this).find('span')` selector is picking them up. Do you still see the duplication if you disable your date picker?

Comment: i believe that like in angular, you're not really supposed to use tools that modify the virtualdom-created and synced live DOM trees, which would confuse the DIFF bewteen what it thinks it needs and what it actually needs with the unknown modification in place.

Comment: @dandavis: That's really useful, I started to search something related to changing the DOM that react related, sounds like it's bad practice. I'm doing some hybrid work between jquery and react so it might produce weird result.

Comment: if i had to guess, i think that when the live span is modified, the virtual plain span is detected to be missing, and re-inserted, and then your jQuery script "fixes" that newly-inserted one too. just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

React best practice is to abstain from using jQuery DOM modifying methods altogether. Most jQuery plugins will conflict with React's DOM-diffing and cause hard to fix issues.

In your case, there is a port of bootstrap-datepicker called [react-bootstrap-daterangepicker](https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker). I would see if that would work for your project before attempting to mix jQuery with React.